# Best way to store referrer?

Tags: php, session, cookies, store

I have a site with thousands of users. Each user have an unique ID, that they can share with their friends, and in that way get referrals.

What would you recommend the best way to store the $_GET['referral']; from the URL?

Comment: if it's coming in as a query parameter, it'll be in your server's access log. If nothing else, you can get the referals from the logs using most any kind of log analysis package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unique referral IDs should be stored in a database.

For the duration of a user's session, you can store the ID in his session like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['referral_id'] = $_GET['referral'];
```